# using callCC with higher-order functions in R

Tags: r, functional-programming, continuations

I'm trying to figure out how to get R's callCC function for short-circuiting evalutation of a function to work with functions like lapply and Reduce.

**Motivation**

This would make Reduce and and lapply have asymptotic efficiency > O(n), by allowing you to
exit a computation early.

For example, if I'm searching for a value in a list I could map a 'finder' function across the list, and the second it is found lapply stops running and that value is returned (much like breaking a loop, or using a return statement to break out early).

The problem is I am having trouble writing the functions that lapply and Reduce should take using a style that callCC requires.

**Example**

Say I'm trying to write a function to find the value '100' in a list: something equivalent to

```
imperativeVersion <- function (xs) {
    for (val in xs) if (val == 100) return (val)
}
```

The function to pass to lapply would look like:

```
find100 <- function (val) { if (val == 100) SHORT_CIRCUIT(val)  }
functionalVersion <- function (xs) lapply(xs, find100)
```

This (obviously) crashes, since the short circuiting function hasn't been defined yet.

```
callCC( function (SHORT_CIRCUIT) lapply(1:1000, find100) )
```

The problem is that this also crashes, because the short circuiting function wasn't around when find100 was defined. I would like for something similar to this to work.

the following works because SHORT_CIRCUIT IS defined at the time that the function passed to lapply is created.

```
callCC(
    function (SHORT_CIRCUIT) {
        lapply(1:1000, function (val) {
             if (val == 100) SHORT_CIRCUIT(val)
        })
)
```

How can I make SHORT_CIRCUIT be defined in the function passed to lapply without defining it inline like above?

I'm aware this example can be achieved using loops, reduce or any other number of ways. I am looking for a solution to the problem of using callCC with lapply and Reduce in specific.

If I was vague or any clarification is needed please leave a comment below. I hope someone can help with this :)

Edit One:
The approach should be 'production-quality'; no deparsing functions or similar black magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a soluton to this problem:

```
find100 <- function (val) {
    if (val == 100) SHORT_CIRCUIT(val)
}

short_map <- function (fn, coll) {


    callCC(function (SHORT_CIRCUIT) {

        clone_env <- new.env(parent = environment(fn))
        clone_env$SHORT_CIRCUIT <- SHORT_CIRCUIT

        environment(fn) <- clone_env
        lapply(coll, fn)

    })
}

short_map(find100, c(1,2,100,3))
```

The trick to making higher-order functions work with callCC is to assign the short-circuiting function into the input functions environment before carrying on with the rest of the program. I made a clone of the environment to avoid unintended side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using metaprogramming in R.
@alexis_laz's approach was in fact already metaprogramming.
However, he used strings which are a dirty hack and error prone. So you did well to reject it.

The correct way to approach @alexis_laz's approach would be by wrangling on code level. In base R this is done using `substitute()`. There are however better packages e.g. `rlang` by Hadley Wickham. But I give you a base R solution (less dependency).

```
lapply_ <- function(lst, FUN) {
  eval.parent(
    substitute(
      callCC(function(return_) {
        lapply(lst_, FUN_)
      }), 
      list(lst_ = lst, FUN_=substitute(FUN))))
}
```

Your `SHORT_CIRCUIT` function is actually a more general, control flow `return` function (or a `break` function which takes an argument to return it). Thus, I call it `return_`.

We want to have a `lapply_` function, in which we can in the `FUN=` part use a `return_` to `break` out of the usual `lapply()`.

As you showed, this is the aim:

```
callCC(
  function (return_) {
    lapply(1:1000, function (x) if (x == 100) return_(x))
  }
)
```

Just with the problem, that we want to be able to generalize this expression.
We want

```
callCC(
  function(return_) lapply(lst, FUN_)
)
```

Where we can use inside the function definition we give for `FUN_` the `return_`.
We can let, however, the function defintion see `return_` only if we insert the function definition code into this expression.
This exactly @alexis_laz tried using string and eval.
Or you did this by manipulating environment variables.

We can safely achieve the insertion of literal code using `substitute(expr, replacer_list)` where `expr` is the code to be manipulated and `replacer_list` is the lookup table for the replacement of code.
By `substitute(FUN)` we take the literal code given for `FUN=` for `lapply_` without evaluating it. This expression returns literal quoted code (better than the string in @alexis_laz's approach).

The big `substitute` command says: "Take the expression `callCC(function(return_) lapply(lst_, FUN_))` and replace `lst_` in this expression by the list given for `coll` and `FUN_` by the literal quoted expression given for `FUN`.

This replaced expression is then evaluated in the parent environment (`eval.parent()`) meaning: the resulting expression replaces the `lapply_()` call and is executed exactly where it was placed.

Such use of `eval.parent()` (or `eval( ... , envir=parent.frame())`) is fool proof. (otherwise, tidyverse packages wouldn't be production level ...).

So in this way, you can generalize `callCC()` calls.

```
lapply_(1:1000, FUN=function(x) if (x==100) return_(x))
## [1] 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be of use, but:

```
    find100 <- "function (val) { if (val == 100) SHORT_CIRCUIT(val)  }"
    callCC( function (SHORT_CIRCUIT) lapply(1:1000, eval(parse(text = find100))) )
    #[1] 100
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but evalparse is too far on the hacky side for my purposes. Deparsing a function to a string isn't always possible, and all information about the enclosing environment that the function was defined in is lost. (this will break many functions).